# Any ideas on how to jump back and forth between a file and its corresponding unit test?

Tags: key-bindings, jump

Here's an example of a typical project structure for me:

```
components/a.js
components/common/b.js
tests/unit/components/a.test.js
tests/unit/components/common/b.test.js
```

Notice that inside the `/unit` folder, I mimic the structure of the project.

Comment: I never used it personally but I believe [vim-projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) does what you are looking for.

Comment: Kind of creating `after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` with custom `:balt ...` command and then jump with `<C-^>` as usual.